# SQL Server: Adding a column increases table size more than expected

Tags: sql-server

To migrate to a new schema, I am doing two things to a table:

1. Changing a VARCHAR column to NVARCHAR
2. Adding a BIGINT column

To test how this affects size, I generated 180,000 rows. The VARCHAR column I am changing is set to null on every row.

Here are the results of sp_spaceused (all sizes in KB):

```
          rows     reserved     data   index_size  unused
          ----     --------     ----   ----------  ------
before    180000     110976     43168       67288     520
after     180000     120320     52536       67296     488
```

So the data grew by more than 9MB. I would have expected it to grow by only 1.4 MB, because I added an 8-byte numeric column.

If I just create the table and generate the data, the size looks more like what I would expect:

```
          rows     reserved     data   index_size  unused
          ----     --------     ----   ----------  ------
        180000       117760    46184        71352     224
```

So is there something about adding a column that causes sp_spaceused to report more data in use than was actually added?

Comment: What is the table definition? How did you generate the rows?

Comment: Did you rebuild your clustered index afterward?  You probably got all sorts of page splits by requiring an extra eight bytes on each row.  Check the number of pages used, I'll bet it increased quite a bit.

Comment: Wouldn't changing `VARCHAR` to `NVARCHAR` double the string lengths? This might cause a some forwarded records as well.

Comment: @mustaccio they say all the values are null so this would be zero length. Forwarded records only apply to heaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No one really explained why this happened.  Dave Gugg gave you a great hint.

SQL stores rows in pages.  (That are about 8K, but not exactly)  And a row must fit into one page (not really, given long varchars can be stored on a separate page using a pointer - but yours are all null, so lets ignore that for now.)

The pages are allocated in clusters.

When you inserted the rows you had a nice fresh set of pages and clusters and the rows were all neat.

As you make any change, but particularly something like adding a column, SQL must update every row.

Updating any row requires changing one or more pages - because the changed row may no longer fit on the same page.  In fact, because of the way rollback works, I think that sometimes SQL actually likes to move changed rows to a new page.

So, your tightly arranged rows got distributed and took many more pages and clusters.  Over time with many changes, this averages out.  Not every update adds pages - but adding a column is making each row larger and less likely to fit with its prior neighbors.

We cannot be more specific because you did not provide the schema.  If you had, we'd have a sense of expected rows per page before and after your change.

Comment: Great explanation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As you all expected, the problem was fragmentation. After generating the data and migrating to the new schema with the additional column, I checked fragmentation using sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats. The avg_fragmentation_in_percent for the clustered index was 98.8%. Rebuilding reduced it to 0.4%, and sp_spaceused show the data size dropping from 52MB to 29MB.

Thanks for all the great help.